# How to add formatting to react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

This seems insane, but I wasn't really able to find a good solution on this:

Assume you have the following translation file:

en.json

```
{
  stuff: "<p> random text <b>more random text</b>. more random text {{_distance}}) even more random text <b>and more</b> random text</p>"
}
```

Now I can call this like so:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('stuff', { _distance }) }} />
```

This is pretty dangerous, especially in a case where I want to have external employees work on my translation files. The documentation talks of some seemingly-random replacement gags:

```
translations: {
  stuff: "<1> random text <3>more random text</3>. more random text {{_distance}}) even more random text <7>and more</7> random text</1>"
}
```

I guessed the replacements tags for the example. But even if they were correct. Again some external translator would not be able to provide formatted text in his language.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Did you already try Trans component? https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: Jupp, ultimately worked with trans component, however it is required to also add     const i18nOptions = {
        react: { transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ['br', 'i', 'b', 'p', 'strong'] },
    }